# Do you know if he didn't go to the party? Is this question correct?

Tags: tenses, questions

I was wondering if this question is correct or not? and if not, why not?

> **Do you know if he didn't go to the party?**

It sounds kind of strange. I feel

> **'Do you know if he went to the party?'**

is better... but i'm not sure why.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is grammatically correct, but it is not, in normal circumstances, idiomatic. Those 'normal circumstances' would be a simple routine enquiry. If however there had been some discussion about who did and who didn't attend the party, so that one's interlocutor was fully aware of the question's significance - it then might be possible to use it. But it becomes more idiomatic if you replace *if* with *that*, which indicates that confirmation is being sought. Otherwise, one might ask *Do you know whether he went to the party?*. Or *Can you confirm that he was not at the party?*.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if he didn't go to the party? can be rephrased to:

Do you know if he *was absent from*/absented himself from the party?

It might be used when everybody around you thinks he was *present* at the party, but you are the only one who is not sure and you want to ask someone what you want to know.

I don't think it is incorrect, but at the same, you don't have to ask that way for a simple question of whether he was present at the party.

I would say it might be quite unusual to ask that way.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, for “I know that he didn’t go to the party”.

[WS2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279704/do-you-know-if-he-didnt-go-to-the-party-is-this-question-correct#comment-619860)’s comment explains neatly why it is strange, but also why such a question might be constructed.

Comment: The questioin for “I know that he didn’t go to the party” would rather be *Do you know (for sure) **that** he didn't go to the party?*